# Get value from dictionary key while for each and its element is string

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

how can I get value from key while the element in for each is just a string?

Here is my code:

```
public List<int[]> FindAllLetters(List<string> lettersOnBoard, Dictionary<string, int> frequency)
{
        List<int[]> lettersExistLeft = new List<int[]>();

        foreach (string letter in frequency.Keys)
        {
            int exist = 0;
            int dictionaryFrquencyLetter = 0;

            exist = lettersOnBoard.Count(n => n == letter);
            dictionaryFrquencyLetter = letter.GiveValueOfKey() //< how get value of key(letter) ?

        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Something tells me this code could be simpler. What exactly do you expect to get from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
dictionaryFrquencyLetter = frequency[letter];
```

Comment: Ha! You were faster xD Thanks, I'm just too much tired.

Answer (score 3):

The same way you get any value from a dictionary with a given key:

```
dictionaryFrquencyLetter = frequency[letter];
```

However (assuming that the rather pointless code you have posted will be extended at some point to do something useful) if you are iterating through the dictionary keys collection why not just iterate through the items e.g.

```
foreach (var item in frequency)
{
    var key = item.Key
    var value = item.Value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for this:

```
dictionaryFrquencyLetter = frequency[letter];
```

Comment: Ha, StackOverflow didn't tell me there were other answers. I think you get the picture.